# what does undefined reference to a recursive function mean?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am getting the following error while compiled using gdb:

```
/tmp/ccYfysv0.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `reverse'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

other answers say it might be due to mispelling of the function name, but here is the code that I am trying to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int reverse(int,int,int*);
int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int temp,n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    int y = reverse(n,(int)0,&a[0]);

    int reverse(int o,int k,int* p){ 
        
        temp = *(p+k);
        *(p+k)=*(p+o);
        *(p+o) = temp;
        o=o-1;k=k+1;
       
        if(o==k)
        {
           return 0;
        }
        else if((k+1)==o){
            temp = *(p+k);
            *(p+k)=*(p+o);
            *(p+o) = temp;
             return 0;
        }
        else{
          reverse(o,k,p);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it with g++, I get the following error:

```
expected a ';'
```

could someone please help me out with this problem.

Comment: You can't define functions inside of functions. Move the definition of `reverse()` somewhere outside `main()`

Comment: `I am getting the following error while compiled using gdb` - really, you use gdb to compile the code?

Comment: You cant define static arrays (`int a[n];`) at runtime like that. For this use either `new/ delete` or `malloc/ free` to allocate the memory (`size = sizeof(int) * n`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't define `reverse` inside of `main` like that. Move it out separate from main, something on this general order:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse(int o,int k,int* p){ 
    
    temp = *(p+k);
    *(p+k)=*(p+o);
    *(p+o) = temp;
    o=o-1;k=k+1;
    
    if(o==k)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if((k+1)==o){
        temp = *(p+k);
        *(p+k)=*(p+o);
        *(p+o) = temp;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        reverse(o,k,p);
    }
}

int main() {
    int temp,n,i;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    int y = reverse(n,(int)0,&a[0]);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault waiting to happen because of `int a[n];`.

Comment: @DhirajWishal true, given a large enough `n`, but better if you call it Undefined Behaviour. All sorts of evil smurf can happen (or not happen) when the stack overflows and a segfault is one of the nicer possibilities.

Comment: @DhirajWishal: Yes, but it's written in C, and the fact that C includes such a poorly considered "feature" (and it's not something ancient and deprecated either) seems to indicate that C uses simply don't care much about such considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You *declared* a function `reverse()`, but you did not *define* it outside of `main()` (you can't define a function inside of another function, like you did), so the linker can't find the implementation of `reverse()` to satisfy `main`'s call to it.

Also, your `reverse()` function is missing a `return` statement in the final `else` block.

Try this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse(int,int,int*);

int main()
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    int y = reverse(n,0,&a[0]);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);

    return 0;
}

int reverse(int o,int k,int* p)
{
    int temp = *(p+k);
    *(p+k)=*(p+o);
    *(p+o) = temp;
    o=o-1;k=k+1;
       
    if(o==k)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if((k+1)==o){
        temp = *(p+k);
        *(p+k)=*(p+o);
        *(p+o) = temp;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return reverse(o,k,p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault waiting to happen because of `int a[n];`.